# What do I put under Relationship Length on my references for a job application

Tags: applications, references

Im trying to complete my references on my application and i have everything except for the final box which just says, “relationship length”. There was already a space for relationship, so i’m unsure what to put there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be an English language question. "length" means "the amount of time occupied by something". So "relationship length" means "the amount of time occupied by the relationship". If you've had different relationships with them, I would list all of them and add up the durations.

Answer (score 4):

That would typically be how long you worked with that person for. So if they were your advisor in university for 3 years, you would put "3 years".

Answer (score 3):

Under "relationship" put "supervisor" or "coworker"

Then under "relationship length" put "2 years" if they were your supervisor for 2 years, etc